# Unable to get LinkedIN's login button

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to web programming. I am here because my extensive search did not yield results. I expected a login button from linked in for the following code;

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
api_key: the_app_key;
authorize: false;
lang: en_US;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="IN/Login"></script>
Get the button...
</body>
</html>
```

I have copy pasted the_app_key; with the app key I got from Linkedin. I am not able get the login button with this code. I tried this code on both firefox and Chromium.